# Cant connect to AWS EC2 with ssh after deleting VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am working on my bachelor thesis which involves creating a lab environment for the Introduction to cloud computing subject.
Recently found out that there was 1 extra VPC in the landing zone, decided to delete it in case someone accidentally chooses it and they have problems. Turns out I had been using that same VPC to test labs and now I cant connect to a EC2 instance old or new through ssh or aws connect even with the root account using the default Control Tower VPC.

First guess was that the internet gateway was configured poorly but adding a gateway did not solve the problem.

Has anybody had the same issue ?

Comment: You would not be able to delete vpc with an instance in it. Maybe you have deleted an internet gateway instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to connect to an EC2 instance via SSH over the internet, you must make sure that all of the following conditions are met, regardless of whether you provision the AWS account and the VPC via AWS Control Tower or any other means:

1. at least one of the security groups attached to the Elastic Network Interface (ENI) assigned to the instance to which you establish the connection must have an inbound rule for SSH to allow from the originating host (you).
2. the ENI must have a public IP address assigned to it.
3. the subnet the EC2 instance is deployed in must have an ALLOW rule for incoming and outgoing IP packets sent/received from SSH (this will be the case for a subnet in the default VPC).
4. you must have an internet gateway in your VPC.
5. the route table of the subnet the EC2 instance is deployed in must have an entry for the internet gateway.
6. for SSH connection directly from your computer, you must be in posession of the private SSH key with which you initiate the connection and the EC2 instance must have been configured to use the corresponding key.

Comment: Thank you.
I had a Routing table attached to the VPC but not to the subnet.
ssh connection works fine now.